# Simplifying a nested for loop with comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying to simplify a nested for loop through a dictionary to build a list of unique values (the room sizes that are lists in the nested dictionary values). I have gotten the code reduced down to 4 lines, but was curious if it can be reduced to 1 line through list comprehension in any way.

This is an example python dictionary:

```
otas = {
    Orbitz: {
        u'Las Vegas': [u'1 Bedroom Suite B-side']
    },
    Expedia: {
        u'Los Angeles': [u'2 Bedroom Lockoff', u'1 Bedroom Deluxe (A-side)', u'3 Bedroom Deluxe']
    },
    Priceline: {
        u'New York': [u'1 Bedroom Deluxe (A-side)']
    },
    Travelocity: {
        u'Chicago': [u'1 Bedroom Deluxe (A-side)', u'2 Bedroom Lockoff']
    }
}
```

And this is the four lines of code:

```
rooms = []
for resort in otas.values():
    for room in resort.values():
        rooms += [r for r in room if r not in rooms]
```

I know there is nothing *wrong* with the way i'm currently doing it. I'm mostly curious if it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is the rooms with no repetition in the otas dictionary then:

```
rooms = set([r for resort in otas.values() for room in resort.values() for r in room])
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could use a triply-"nested" set comprehension.

```
rooms = {roomtype
         for service  in otas
         for location in otas[service]
         for roomtype in otas[service][location]}
```

If you want a list back, just wrap that in a call to `list`.

Comment: Great answer! I did not realize one could do that in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
rooms = list(set(reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [item for x in otas.values() for item in x.values()])))
```